# Javascript cannot process JSON text file

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, json, xmlhttprequest

I am following some tutorial to pass a JSON text file from server to display the data after some javascript processing on a html file.  As a test, try to display a LI of one column, but cannot get any output in the browser.   Your help is appreciated.

I tried two approaches.

Approach 1 xmlhttp:

Apparently, the browser complain about the html format:
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected string (15:08:42:080 | error, javascript)
  at testJSON3.html:12

Is my xmlhttp call format correct?

Thank you for your help in advance.

Here's JSON text myTutorial.txt:

```
[
{
"active":"1",
"courseCode":"208.01.00",
"courseName":"course name 1",
"eventDesc":"2015 class of course name 1"
},
{
"active":"1",
"courseCode":"208.01.00",
"courseName":"course name21",
"eventDesc":"2015 class of course name "
}
]
```

And processed by the below html to process the xmlhttp access to the file on server localhost directory phpTWLLT

```
<!DOCTYPE html>


<html>
    <head>
        <script type='text/javascript' src='js/jquery.min.js'></script>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
    </head>
    <body>

        <div id="id01"></div>

        <script>
            var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            var url = "http://localhost/phpTWLLT/myTutorial.txt";

            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
                if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                    var myArr = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
                    myFunction(myArr);
                }
            };
            xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
            xmlhttp.send();

            function myFunction(arr) {
                var out = "";
                var i;
                for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
                    out += '<li'> + arr[i].courseCode +'</li><br>';
                }
                document.getElementById("id01").innerHTML = out;
            }
        </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

Approach 2 getJSON():

This one is interesting. If the server side is static array ($DEBUG = true:), javascript is able to process and get browser display.  But fail when generate the text from mysql ($DEBUG = false).

I am scratching my head to get the $DEBUG=false work?  Apparently, both cases generated a valid JSON text.

If $DEBUG is set true,

output from localhost/phpTWLLT/json_encode_array.php

[{"active":"0","first_name":"Darian","last_name":"Brown","age":"28","email":"darianbr@example.com"},{"active":"1","first_name":"John","last_name":"Doe","age":"47","email":"john_doe@example.com"}]

the list displayed in browser.
0
1

If $DEBUG is set false,

output from localhost/phpTWLLT/json_encode_array.php

[{"active":"1"},{"active":"1"}]

The browser display is blank.

html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--
To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
and open the template in the editor.
-->
<html>
    <head>
        <!--
        <script type='text/javascript' src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js'>    </script>
        -->
    <script type='text/javascript' src='js/jquery.min.js'></script>

    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    </head>    
    <body>

    <!-- this UL will be populated with the data from the php array -->
    <ul></ul>

    <script type='text/javascript'>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            /* call the php that has the php array which is json_encoded */
            //$.getJSON('json_encoded_array.php', function(data) { 
            $.getJSON('json_encoded_array.php', function (data) {
                /* data will hold the php array as a javascript object */

                 $.each(data, function (key, val) {

                 $('ul').append('<li id="' + key + '">' + val.active  + '</li>');
                 });

            });
        });
        </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

PHP script: json_encoded_array.php

```
<?php

/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */



/* set out document type to text/javascript instead of text/html */


$DEBUG = true;

if ($DEBUG) {
    header("Content-type: text/javascript");
    $arr = array(
        array(
            "active" => "0",
            "first_name" => "Darian",
            "last_name" => "Brown",
            "age" => "28",
            "email" => "darianbr@example.com"
        ),
        array(
            "active" => "1",
            "first_name" => "John",
            "last_name" => "Doe",
            "age" => "47",
            "email" => "john_doe@example.com"
        ) 
    );
} else {
    require_once('connection.php');
// $m_id= 8 has many enrolled course and 11 got exactly one course enrolled. 
    $m_id = 8;
    $p_id = 1;

    $qry1 = "SELECT distinct event.active as active, subject.code as 'courseCode', subject.name as     'courseName', event.event_desc as 'eventDesc' FROM applicant, event, subject, part where applicant.applicant_id = $m_id and applicant.event_id = event.id and event.subject_id=subject.id and part.id = subject.owner_id and part.id = $p_id order by event.active DESC, event.from_month DESC ";
    mysqli_set_charset($bd, 'utf-8');
    $result = mysqli_query($bd, $qry1);

    $arr = array();
    $i = 0;
    if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
        while ( $rs = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)  ) {
             $colhead = "active";
            $str = $rs['active'];

            $arr[$i] = array($colhead => $str);
            $i++;

                // just generate two record for testing
                if ($i === 2)
                break;

        }
    } 
}
echo json_encode($arr);
?>
```

Comment: `'<li'>` should be `'<li>'`, please always check your syntax

Comment: @Patrick, thank you for your suggestion.  However, there is still no list displayed in the browser.

Comment: Are you getting the exact same error, maybe a different error, or none at all?

Answer (score 0):

For approach 2, did you try debugging the javascript code to check if the data variable contains the expected data?

You could also check the network tab to see if the response data sent from your server is correct.

Comment: If I ran the localhost/phpTWLLT/json_encoded_array.php generated json formated text.  If $DEBUG=true, browser output: [{"active":"0","first_name":"Darian","last_name":"Brown","age":"28","email":"darianbr@example.com"},{"active":"1","first_name":"John","last_name":"Doe","age":"47","email":"john_doe@example.com"}]             If $DEBUG=false, browser output:  [{"active":"1"},{"active":"1"}]

Comment: Try opening the browser's debugger(F12) and then load the html file. In the debugger's network tab, you will be able to see the HTTP request and the response - check for differences between the debug and non-debug version.